# Why does makeViewWithIdentifier:owner: return different types sporadically?

Tags: cocoa, nstableview, nsview

Hello and thanks for reading.  I am trying to populate a view based NSTableView from an array of People objects.  In my setup i'm using Storyboards with two xib files (one for the main tableview and the other for my custom view).

The call to makeViewWithIdentifier:owner: within the delegate method "tableView viewForTableColumn row" is returning different types for no obvious reason.  Sometimes when i compile it returns objects of type "MyOView" (see Console Output 1) which is my custom view class and yet other times when i compile (despite literally no change in my code) it returns NSTextField (see Console Output 2)

Why is this happening?

**Console Output 1:**
*class name of cell is: Saddle.MyOView
class name of cell is: Saddle.MyOView*

**Console Output 2:**
*Could not cast value of type 'NSTextField' (0x7fff7e1bbf40) to 'Saddle.MyOView' (0x100017980).*
(lldb)

Here is my implementation of tableView viewForTableColumn Row...

```
func tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView? {
    let cell = tableView.makeViewWithIdentifier("MyOView", owner: self) as! MyOView
    println("class name of cell is: " + cell.className)
    let person : Person = allPeopleInRace[row]
    cell.itemNumber.stringValue = person.number.description
    cell.itemName.stringValue =  person.name
    return cell
}
```

In the ViewController in viewDidLoad() i have registered the second nib

```
let nib = NSNib(nibNamed: "MyOView", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
mainTableView.registerNib(nib!, forIdentifier: "MyOView")
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some more digging around I realised that I hadn't named my custom cell Xib.  Hope this is helpful to someone else.